# class oop realions cpp

Tags: c++, class, oop

i started a new oop course in c++, sorry for my bad english.

i read some info about generalization (inheritance), aggregation, and association.
 still didn't understand this example:

lets say a Taxi think of a car, contains sub class like Engine and Wheels..
i want to "allowing Taxi" access to all of the fields of sub classes (or thats what i think i want, plz tell me if there is better ways)

engine.h:

```
class Engine{

public:
    Engine(status nstatus, int npower, double nEngineVer) :EngineStatus(nstatus), power(npower), EngineVer(nEngineVer)
    {};
private:
    status EngineStatus;
    int power;
    double EngineVer;
};
```

Taxi.h:

```
#include "engine.h"

class Taxi{
public:
    Taxi(int id, int ,km, const Engine &engine) :id(id),km(km),engine(engine){};
    void printMe(){
        cout << id << ' ' << km << ' '<< endl;
    }
private:
    Taxi();     //default Ctor is private! we dont want to create broken Taxi e.g no engine
    int id;
    int km;
    Engine engine;
};
```

lets say if i used printMe i want to print the whole values of Taxi,
how should i do it(allowing acces to Engine values)

tnks all answers!

Comment: Don't do it. Give `Engine` the ability to print itself and call that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also implement so called "Getters" for your Engine-Class. Thats, when you are a more experienced programmer, the most common method to access attributes of classes.

Something like this:

```
class Engine {

public: 
  Engine(status nstatus, int npower, double nEngineVer) 
    : EngineStatus(nstatus), power(npower), EngineVer(nEngineVer) 
  {}

  int getPower() const { return power; }

private: 
   status EngineStatus; 
   int power; 
   double EngineVer;
};


class Taxi {

public: 
  Taxi(int id, int ,km, const Engine &engine) 
    : id(id), km(km), engine(engine)
  {}

  void printMe()
  { 
     cout << engine.getPower() << endl; 
  } 

 private:
   int id;
   int km;
   Engine engine;
};
```

You can do the rest alone I won't do your homework.
And you don't need to set the default constructor to private if you created a custom one, just don't declare it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the `Engine` values, you could write a function in `Engine` to do that:

```
class Engine {
    // ...
    void printMe(){
        cout << EngineStatus << ' ' << power << ' ' <<
                EngineVer << endl;
    }
    // ...
};
```

And then just call it from `Taxi`:

```
void printMe() {
    cout << id << ' ' << km << ' ';
    engine.printMe();
}
```

Comment: ok, tnks
i think it could be fine for printMe,
i think the correct relation is a Taxi "has a" engine "has a" wheels.
it's a Aggregation  right?
so can i use public somwhere or friend or ?
if it's to complicated ill understand,

still tnks

Comment: @user3876191 There's no reason to use friendship or to make things public in this case. If the `Taxi` needs to access individual members from `Engine`, you could always add a getter.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic method is to declare Engine variables as `public` instead of private. In this case, from a Taxi instance you can access directly to for example `engine.power`.